# ¿Cómo agregar una libreria jar a java?

Tags: java, jar

estoy intentando usar una Liberia llamada AutoCompleter.jar para java, el  chiste es que estoy usando un editor de texto(**Sublime Text**), es decir que no estoy utilizando un IDE como Netbeans o eclipse.

Lo que intente fue añadir el archivo .jar en el CLASSPATH pero al importar  al parecer no la encuentra.

Comment: Cómo la agregaste al classpath? Que problema tienes al compilar/ejecutar?

Comment: @E.Betanzos Coloque la ruta "C:\Users\Jorge\Desktop\Proyect\AutoCompleter.jar" , entonces en mi código coloco: import Autocompleter y me sale error: '.' expected

Comment: @JorgeRojasC. es un proyecto **maven** el que tienes? Tiene un archivo *pom.xml*?

Comment: @andres no e sun proyecto maven, solo estoy creando una interfaz con javafx en un editor de texto